# Using p5's functions without the setup/draw format

Tags: javascript, python, import, p5.js

I'm relatively new to Javascript, and i was tinkering around with the [p5](https://p5js.org/) library. In Python i can import a single function from a library using the `from x import y statement`:

```
from subprocess import check_output
```

My question is, there is a way to do the same thing with p5 without using the `setup/draw` format? Say, for example, i want to use the `noise` function in one of my scripts; can i import and use that function only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With questions like this, it's best to put together a test to try things out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Noise Test</title>
    <script src="p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(noise(100));    
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  Noise Test, check the console.
  </body>
</html>
```

Here we're loading the `p5.js` library, and then trying to call the `noise()` function. If we run that, we get an error:

```
Did you just try to use p5.js's noise() function? If so, you may want to move it into your sketch's setup() function.

For more details, see: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup

index.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: noise is not defined
```

We can go to that url to read about what's going on:

> In global mode, p5 variable and function names are not available
> outside setup(), draw(), mousePressed(), etc. (Except in the case
> where they are placed inside functions that are called by one of these
> methods.)
>
> The explanation for this is a little complicated, but it has to do
> with the way the library is setup in order to support both global and
> instance mode. To understand what's happening, let's first look at the
> order things happen when a page with p5 is loaded (in global mode).
>
> 1. Scripts in are loaded.
> 2. of HTML page loads (when this is complete, the onload event fires, which then triggers step 3).
> 3. p5 is started, all functions are added to the global namespace.
>
> So the issue is that the scripts are loaded and evaluated before p5 is
> started, when it's not yet aware of the p5 variables. If we try to
> call them here, they will cause an error. However, when we use p5
> function calls inside setup() and draw() this is ok, because the
> browser doesn't look inside functions when the scripts are first
> loaded. This is because the setup() and draw() functions are not
> called in the user code, they are only defined, so the stuff inside of
> them isn't run or evaluated yet.
>
> It's not until p5 is started up that the setup() function is actually
> run (p5 calls it for you), and at this point, the p5 functions exist
> in the global namespace.

### So, no, you can't use `p5.js` functions without the `setup()` and `draw()` functions.

That being said, you could define a callback function that you call from `setup()`, that way you know the `p5.js` functions are available:

```
<script src="p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function doYourStuff(){
        console.log(noise(100));        
    }

    function setup(){
        doYourStuff();
    }
</script>
```

### Alternatively, you could use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace).

This involves manually creating an instance of `p5` and using that to call functions directly instead of calling them globally:

```
<script src="p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var p5 = new p5();
    console.log(p5.noise(100));
</script>
```

### You could also dig through the source.

There isn't a good way to import a single function, but you could do a ctrl+f search of the unminified source for `p5.js` and look for the `noise()` function. Then you could copy that into its own file (and any other helper functions it relies on). But that's probably going to be more work than using one of the above approaches, plus it might violate p5.js's copyrights.

Comment: As sad as it makes me to have an incomplete answer... +1 for incredible research.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson Thanks. I definitely understand your confusion, since the `p5.js` functions aren't loaded quite like other JavaScript libraries are. Definitely takes some getting used to.

Comment: @KevinWorkman thank you for this answer, it solved my problem!

Comment: Note that `var p5 = new p5();` can cause the `p5 is not a constructor` error to be thrown. Best to pick a different variable name like `var p5_ = new p5();`.